# if statments are not working with ejs view engine

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm trying to do "Orders page" that has a list of orders in a single page, but it should have seperate sections. One is for "Already made" and the other is for "Pending". It has a simple database with a field "isDone" that is either true or false. So as I imagine, if it is true, then it should appear on "Already made" section, but the problem is, that if statment doesn't work for some reason in .ejs.

```
<body class="container">
        <main>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1>Pending</h1>
            </div>
            <% orders_list.forEach(function(order){ %>
                <% if(order.isDone == false) { %>
                    <div>
                    <h3><a href='<%= order.url %>'><%= order.name %></a> - <%= order.price %> euru</h3>
                    <hr>
                    </div>
                <% } %>
            <% }) %>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1>Already made</h1>
            </div>
            <% orders_list.forEach(function(order){ %>
                <% if(order.isDone == true) { %>
                    <div>
                    <h3><a href='<%= order.url %>'><%= order.name %></a> - <%= order.price %> euru</h3>
                    <hr>
                    </div>
                <% } %>
            <% }) %> 
        </main>
</body>
```

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Order = require('../models/order');

router.get('/orders', function(req, res){
    Order.find({})
    .exec(function(err, list_orders){
      if (err) {return next(err)};
      // If Successful
      res.render('../views/pages/index', {orders_list : list_orders});
    });
  });

module.exports = router;
```

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var OrderSchema = new Schema(
  {
    isDone: {type: Boolean, required: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    quantity: {type: Number, required: true},
    price: {type: Number, required: true},
    phone: {type: Number},
  });

  OrderSchema
  .virtual('url')
  .get(function(){
      return '/order/' + this._id;
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model ('Order', OrderSchema);
```

I expect 'isDone' == true orders to go to 'Already made' section, and 'isDone' == false orders should go to the 'Pending' section. But not even single item appears. Database is connected successfully, if there are no if statments then orders appear on the page.

Comment: can you post the `Order` schema?

Comment: I absolutely forgot about `Order` schema, as I didn't updated it with "isDone". It solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `if` condition you have `quote your true` value because ejs file is taking it as a value instead of a boolean value , so quote your `true` like this and it will work fine.

```
 <% if(orders_list[i].isDone == 'true'){ %>
   <div>
    <h3><a href='<%= orders_list[i].url %>'><%= orders_list[i].name %></a> - <%= orders_list[i].price %> euru</h3>
     <hr>
     </div>
  <% } %>
```

Comment: But then it shows `SyntaxError: Unexpected token for in C:\Users\Minijus\Desktop\Uzsakymai\uzsakymai\views\pages\index.ejs while compiling ejs`

Comment: did you update your closing brackets too like this `<%= } %>` ?

Comment: Yes, still the same

Comment: @Mince I have updated the answer, your code is fine the mistake is you need to quote `true` like this else ejs template use it as a variable due to which your if condition is not working.

Comment: And it still doesn't work. It displays the page with no erros, but if there is 'if' statments, then sections are blank with no orders inside of them.

Comment: The problem was in `Order` schema. Also `true` and `false` statments cannot have quatations. It didn't work after I updated `Order` schema, but it worked after i deleted quotes. Thanks anyways